# How can I animation for image change on Timeout

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm using html/JavaScript web frame. I want to set animation for each image setTimeout Function. Please help me out here.

```
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){ 
           slide1();
        }, 5000);
    }); 
    
    function slide1(){
        
        $('.hero_section_top').css('background-image','url(images/slider/2.jpg)');
        setTimeout(function(){ 
           slide2();
        }, 5000);
    }
    function slide2(){
        $('.hero_section_top').css('background-image','url(images/slider/3.jpg)');
        setTimeout(function(){ 
           slide3();
        }, 5000);
    }
    function slide3(){
        $('.hero_section_top').css('background-image','url(images/slider/1.jpg)');
        setTimeout(function(){ 
           slide1();
        }, 5000);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This is my div      <header class="hero_section_top home1" style="background-image: url('images/slider/1.jpg');">

Answer (score 0):

Put all images in array and check the delay during the loop to do what you want for each slides

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var bgImages = [
      'https://plchldr.co/i/500x250?text=Image2', 
      'https://plchldr.co/i/500x250?text=Image3', 
      'https://plchldr.co/i/500x250?text=Image1'
    ];
    
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      $(bgImages).each(function(index, value) {
        var loopDelay = (index++) * 5000;
        setTimeout(function(){ 
           $('.hero_section_top').css({'background-image':'url(' + value + ')'});

           //console.log(loopDelay);

           if (loopDelay === 0) {
             console.log('do something');
           } else if (loopDelay === 5000) {
             console.log('do something else');
           } else if (loopDelay === 10000) {
             console.clear();
             console.log('loop done');
           }
        }, (loopDelay));
      });
     }, 5000);
});
```

```css
.hero_section_top {
 width:500px;
 height:250px;
 background-image:url('https://plchldr.co/i/500x250?text=Image1');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hero_section_top"></div>
```